# Add a non field related error to an asp mvc form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I'm having some troubles with ASP MVC error handling.

On a form that a user tries to connect to a device. If the uses input an invalid device name, it's pretty straightforward to tell the user the name is invalid.

I'm implementing `IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRulesViolations()` on all my data classes. The `RuleViolation` class has two fields: `PropertyName` and `ErrorMessage` and if I get an error on submit I just call the GetRulesViolations method and set the errors on the ModelState:

```
catch {
     foreach (var issue in device.GetRulesViolations()) {
          ModelState.AddModelError(issue.PropertyName, issue.ErrorMessage);
     }
     return View();
}
```

and with some background asp mvc magic the error appears on the view in the ValidationMessage placeholder for the model.Name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Connect" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now the problem:

If the error i'm getting is something like "Could not connect to the device" that's not a problem related to the `Name` field. It's a message that should appear above the form because it's related to the whole form.

Is there a straightforward way to set this like ModelState.AddError("error message") without telling the key so it would apply to the whole form or should I create an `Error` hidden property on the Data classes and place a validation message for that property above the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, empty field name, like this :

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", issue.ErrorMessage);
```